# Is it possible to fit a latent class regression where the latent class is grouped by 1 variable, but there is a random intercept by another variable?

Tags: r, latent-variable, finite-mixture-model, latent-class

The data generating process I am interested in is the following:

$$y_i=\beta_g x_i+\epsilon_t+\epsilon_i$$
$$S(i)=s, G(s)=g$$

What this means is that that the $i$th observation, which is made of subject $s$, which belongs to latent group $g$ is a linear function of covariate $x$ and some randomness associated with time $t$ and some randomness associated with observation $i$.

Hopefully I didn't butcher the notation too badly.

Same sample code to generate data like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
n_subjects <- 200
n_times <- 5
n_obs <- n_subjects * n_times

sd_t <- 1
sd_obs <- 0.1

group_beta <- c(0.3, 1.5, 2.7)
n_groups <- length(group_beta)

subject_groups <-
  tibble(
    subject = 1:n_subjects,
    g = sample(n_groups, n_subjects, replace = TRUE)
  ) |> mutate(
    group_beta = group_beta[g]
  )

epsilon_t <- rnorm(n = n_times, sd = sd_t)

simulated_data <-
  crossing(subject = 1:n_subjects, t = 1:n_times) |>
  inner_join(subject_groups, by = "subject") |>
  mutate(
    epsilon_t = epsilon_t[t],
    epsilon_obs = rnorm(n = n(), sd = sd_obs),
    x = rnorm(n = n()),
    y = group_beta * x + epsilon_t + epsilon_obs,
    random_label = sample(n_groups, n(), replace = TRUE)
  )
```

If I know the groups upfront, then a standard random effects model is perfect. Using `lme4` for example:

```
m_lmer <- lmer(y ~ x + (x - 1 | g) + (1 | t), data = simulated_data)
```

But I do not know the groups upfront. So I want to use a library designed for latent class regression.

The 2 libraries I have looked at are [flexmix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/index.html) and [lcmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lcmm/index.html). Neither of them seem capable of expressing this simple model, as far as I can tell, but I am new to these techniques so maybe i missed something.

For example with flexmix:

I can do this:

```
m_flexmix = flexmix(. ~ . | subject, model = FLXMRglm(y ~ x - 1), data = simulated_data, k = 3)
```

I can get it to find reasonable latest classes by subject, but it does not do anything about random effects.

Or I can do this, using the interface to `lme4`

```
m_flexmix = flexmix(. ~ . | subject, model = FLXMRglm(y ~ x - 1), data = simulated_data, k = 3)
```

Here I have told it I want latent classes by subject, but I have told it I want random intercept by subject also, which is incorrect.

Or, I can do this:

```
m_flexmix = flexmix(y ~ 1 | t, model = FLXMRlmer(y ~ x - 1, random = ~ 1), data = simulated_data, k = 3)
```

Even though I am telling it I want random intercepts by t, I am also telling it I want latent classes by t.

As a last resort, I can use `lmer` to try to estimate $\epsilon_t$, then subtract that from y and use `flexmix` from there, as in:

```
m_lmer <- lmer(y ~ x - 1 + (1 | t), data = simulated_data)
estimated_epsion_t <- ranef(m_lmer)$t$`(Intercept)`
simulated_data2 <-
  simulated_data |>
  mutate(y2 = y - estimated_epsion_t[t])
m_flexmix <- flexmix(. ~ . | subject, model = FLXMRglm(y2 ~ x - 1), data = simulated_data2, k = 3)
```

This seems to do an alright job in this simulated data, but at no point does it maximize the actual likelihood of interest and would result in incorrect standard errors etc.

So finally my question: is latent class regression not meant to handle cases like mine whereby latent classes are grouped by one variable, but random effects are grouped by another?